# For loop that prints every line to a file. Error

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to make a for loop that prints every line in a list to a file, however I get this error.  Any help? Thanks

```
def write_file(filename, rabbitlist, foxlist, finallist, averagefox, averagerabbit):

    # Opens File for Data Input
    outfile = open(str(filename) + ".csv", 'w')

    # Writes Data to Newly Created File
    finalresult = "\n".join(", ".join(map(str, l)) for l in finallist)
    outfile.write(str("Day, Foxes, Rabbits, , Average Foxes, Average Rabbits\n"))
    lastline = [0, foxlist[0], rabbitlist[0], " ", averagefox, averagerabbit]
    for item in lastline:
        outfile.write(" %s", item)
    outfile.close()
```

The error I get is: `Python: TypeError: takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: If you take a look at your traceback (error message), you will notice that it will tell you that the error is with the `write` method and on what line the error is on.  You can get a general idea about what causes errors from this and you can make your questions more directed from this information.

Answer (score 3):

.write only [accepts 1 parameter](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)  so i think you can do this

```
def write_file(filename, rabbitlist, foxlist, finallist, averagefox, averagerabbit):

    # Opens File for Data Input
    outfile = open(str(filename) + ".csv", 'w')

    # Writes Data to Newly Created File
    finalresult = "\n".join(", ".join(map(str, l)) for l in finallist)
    outfile.write(str("Day, Foxes, Rabbits, , Average Foxes, Average Rabbits\n"))
    lastline = [0, foxlist[0], rabbitlist[0], " ", averagefox, averagerabbit]
    for item in lastline:
        outfile.write(" %s" % item)
    outfile.close()
```

Comment: You don't need `str()` as `"Day, Foxes, Rabbits, , Average Foxes, Average Rabbits\n"` is already a string.

Comment: Yes, I only copy paste the code above and replace this 
`outfile.write(" %s", item)`
for this         `outfile.write(" %s" % item)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are wirting a csv, why not use the `csv` module. Your method then becomes:

```
import csv

def write_file(filename,
               rabbitlist,
               foxlist,
               finallist,
               averagefox,
               averagerabbit):
    header_row = ['Day','Foxes','Rabbits',' ','Average Foxes','Average Rabbits']
    with open(filename,'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(header_row)
        writer.writerows(finallist)
        writer.writerow([0,
                         foxlist[0],
                         rabbitlist[0],
                         " ",
                         averagefox,
                         averagerabbit])
```

The [`with_statement`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) will automatically close the file, and the csv module has `writerows` which does what it the name suggests.

Answer (score 0):

In python write method of File takes only one argument whereas you are passing two.

Either you can do outfile.write(" %s" %item)

Or better way is to use Pickle